# Why am I getting an error when attempting to use the Meteor search-source package?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I followed [this](https://meteorhacks.com/implementing-an-instant-search-solution-with-meteor) tutorial on [meteor search-source](https://github.com/meteorhacks/search-source) and modified the example so it would fit my current needs. 
This is my `collections.js` which is located in my lib directory

```
Guides = new Mongo.Collection("guides");
```

I have following code in my client side controller.

```
var options = {
    keepHistory: 1000 * 60 * 5,
    localSearch: true
};

var fields = ['title'];

GuideSearch = new SearchSource('guides', fields, options);

Template.guide_list.helpers({
    getGuides: function () {
        return GuideSearch.getData({
            transform: function (matchText, regExp) {
                return matchText.replace(regExp, "<b>$&</b>")
            }
        });
    },

    isLoading: function () {
        return GuideSearch.getStatus().loading;
    }
});


Template.guide_list.events({
    "keyup #title": _.throttle(function(e) {
        var text = $(e.target).val().trim();
        GuideSearch.search(text);
    }, 200)
});
```

And this as my server side code

```
SearchSource.defineSource('guides', function(searchText, options) {
  if(searchText) {
    var regExp = buildRegExp(searchText);
    var selector = {title: regExp}
    return Guides.find(selector, options).fetch();
  } else {
    return Guides.find({}, options).fetch();
  }
});

function buildRegExp(searchText) {
  // this is a dumb implementation
  var parts = searchText.trim().split(/[ \-\:]+/);
  return new RegExp("(" + parts.join('|') + ")", "ig");
}
```

For some reason, I receive the following error message when typing something into my input field

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'search.source': Meteor.makeErrorType/errorClass@http://10.0.3.162:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:525:15
._livedata_result@http://10.0.3.162:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:4625:23
Connection/onMessage@http://10.0.3.162:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:3365:7
._launchConnection/self.socket.onmessage/<@http://10.0.3.162:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:2734:11
_.forEach@http://10.0.3.162:3000/packages/underscore.js?46eaedbdeb6e71c82af1b16f51c7da4127d6f285:149:7
._launchConnection/self.socket.onmessage@http://10.0.3.162:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:2733:9
REventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent@http://10.0.3.162:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:173:9
SockJS.prototype._dispatchMessage@http://10.0.3.162:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:1158:5
SockJS.prototype._didMessage@http://10.0.3.162:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:1216:13
SockJS.websocket/that.ws.onmessage@http://10.0.3.162:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:1363:9
```

This is my template code:

```
template(name="guide_list")
    .format-properly
        .container-fluid
            .input-group#adv-search
                .form-horizontal(role="form" method="POST" action="#")
                    .col-md-6
                        .form-group
                            label(for="contain") Guide title
                            input.form-control(type="text" id="title")
                    .col-md-6
                        .form-group
                            label(for="contain") Author
                            input.form-control(type="text" name="author")
                    .col-md-6
                        .form-group
                            label(for="hero") Select a hero
                            select.form-control(name="hero")
                                option(value="all" selected) All Heroes
                                option(value="Druid") Druid
                                option(value="Hunter") Hunter
                                option(value="Mage") Mage
                                option(value="Paladin") Paladin
                                option(value="Priest") Priest
                                option(value="Rogue") Rogue
                                option(value="Shaman") Shaman
                                option(value="Warlock") Warlock
                                option(value="Warrior") Warrior
                    .col-md-6
                        .form-group
                            label(for="filter") Filter by
                            select.form-control(name="filterBy")
                               option(value="0" selected) All guides
                               option(value="most_viewed") Most viewed
                               option(value="top_rated") Top rated
                               option(value="most_commented") Most commented

        .container-fluid
            .table-responsive
                table.table.table-hover
                    thead
                        tr
                            th hero
                            th title
                            th author
                            th updated
                            th dust
                            th
                                span.glyphicon.glyphicon-eye-open
                            th
                                span.glyphicon.glyphicon-heart
                            th
                                span.glyphicon.glyphicon-comment
                    tbody
                        each guides
                            tr
                                td {{hero}}
                                td
                                    a(href="/guide/{{formatId _id}}") {{title}}
                                td {{authorUsername}}
                                td {{moFormat modifiedAt 'YYYY-MM-DD'}}
                                td {{dust}}
                                td {{hitCount}}
                                td {{rating}}
                                td {{commentCount}}

                    tbody
                        each getGuides
                            tr
                                td {{hero}}
                                td
                                    a(href="/guide/{{formatId _id}}") {{title}}
                                td {{authorUsername}}
                                td {{moFormat modifiedAt 'YYYY-MM-DD'}}
                                td {{dust}}
                                td {{hitCount}}
                                td {{rating}}
                                td {{commentCount}}
```

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated!

**Edit:** I updated the `search-source` package to 1.4.2

Comment: `Guides = new Mongo.Collection("guides");` is being defined in the client side script. `Guides` is being called in the server side script as well, but it's not available because it was defined in the client script. Try moving that line of code into a js file in a `lib` folder, so it will be available both on the server and client. If that's not it, can you include the HTML from your template.

Comment: @BrianShamblen The collection declaration wasn't the fault. But I edited my post and posted my template :)

Comment: I believe that this is due to the (undocumented) issue that I mention in my answer. If not, check if there are any errors in the server log. This package needs a bit of love and updating :)

Comment: It seems, the problem is the lack of options in the SearchSource definition, as @MasterAM said. Could you provide a reproduction repo in GitHub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the issue is the lack of `options` passed to the `GuideSearch.search` method.

This leads to the  search definition handler getting `null` for options.

```
SearchSource.defineSource('guides', function(searchText, options) {
  if(searchText) {
    var regExp = buildRegExp(searchText);
    var selector = {title: regExp}
    return Guides.find(selector, options).fetch(); //illegal
  } else {
    return Guides.find({}, options).fetch();
  }
});
```

This results in the collection's `find()` method getting a null `options` arguments, that, if supplied, must be an object (and not `null`).

Therefore, either check for a null `options` in the data source and pass an empty object (or nothing) to the `find()` method, or pass an empty object to the `GuideSearch.search()` method:

```
Template.guide_list.events({
    "keyup #title": _.throttle(function(e) {
        var text = $(e.target).val().trim();
        GuideSearch.search(text, {}); // here
    }, 200)
});
```

You should probably make sure that the `options` are not `null` in the server method as in @webdeb's answer in any case.

Additionally, at the moment some packages (`check` and `ejson`) have to be added as dependencies to your app as the `meteorhacks:search-source` package uses them without declaring a dependency. This is due to change introduced in v1.2.0. (before then those symbols were automatically available to packages).

In order to get have all of the results available initially, you can trigger a search when the template is first created.
Note that this may be fairly costly when you have a lot of data, so you should probably limit the results returned from the search definition handler on the server.

```
Template.guide_list.onCreated(function () {
  GuideSearch.search('', {});
});
```

In order to display the title correctly in the search results, you could use `Spacebars.SafeString()` so that blaze knows to render it as HTML.

```
Template.guide_list.helpers({
    getGuides: function () {
        return GuideSearch.getData({
            transform: function (matchText, regExp) {
              return Spacebars.SafeString(matchText.replace(regExp, "<b>$&</b>"))
            }
        });
    },
    formatId: function(id) {
      return id;
    },
    moFormat: function(date, format) {
        return moment(date).format(format);
    },
    isLoading: function () {
        return GuideSearch.getStatus().loading;
    }
});

Template.guide_list.events({
    "keyup #title": _.throttle(function(e) {
        var text = $(e.target).val().trim();
        GuideSearch.search(text, {/* your options here */});
    }, 200)
});
```

or, alternatively, use the triple brace notation:

```jade
a(href="/guide/{{formatId _id}}") {{{title}}}
```

*Warning*: be sure to sanitize your `matchText` when doing this.

Publications should have nothing to do with the results, as the package uses its own collection.

Comment: I'm intrigued. I have a working version on my machine. The only things I had to do is add `check` and `ejson`, as the package uses them without declaring a dependency (as they are not automatically available as they were before v1.2.0) and make sure that the `options` argument provided to `Guides.find()` on the server was not `null`.

Comment: YOU are the man! now it works like charm =)! Just had to add the `check` and `ejson` package. Would be probably good if you would add that to your answer then :) by the way, when I render my template initially no results are there. Just when I search for fields they appear. What do you do, to display all the possible entries available in the beginning before the user searched something?

Comment: Glad to hear that. I added a few explanations to get you started and solve some small issues that I found.

Comment: Thank you so, so much!!! I really appreciate your effort and this answer is perfect now :D! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer from @MasterAM, but to solve this problem just put this in your `SearchSource` function:

```
 SearchSource.defineSource('guides', function(searchText, options) {
  options = options || {}; // to be sure, that options is at least an empty object
  if(searchText) {
    var regExp = buildRegExp(searchText);
  ...
```